# Python: difference between *args and list in a remote function

Tags: python, synchronization, ray

Define a list

```
g = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Version 1

```
@ray.remote
def f(*g):     
    return np.mean(g, axis=0)
f_ids = [f.remote(*g) for _ in range(10)]
print(ray.get(f.remote(*f_ids)))
```

Version 2

```
@ray.remote
def f(g):    # g is object ID list
    return np.mean(g, axis=0)
f_ids = [f.remote(g) for _ in range(10)]
print(ray.get(f.remote(f_ids)))
```

The first code works fine, however Version 2 does not work. The error message is

> ray.get(f.remote(f_ids))
>   unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'common.ObjectID' and 'common.ObjectID'

The reason I want to do something like Version 2 is that I actually want to do something like the following

```
@remote
def f(g1, g2):    # g1 and g2 are object ID lists
    ...           # do something here
```

I do not know how to make the `g1` and `g2` as `*g1` and `*g2` so I come up wit Version 2. Why does Version 2 not work? How can I fix it?

The reference code is here
https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example-parameter-server.html#synchronous-parameter-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When arguments are passed into a Ray remote function, any argument of type `ray.ObjectID` is automatically replaced by the unpacked value (meaning `ray.get` is called under the hood). All other arguments are unchanged.

That's why if if you define a remote function like

```
# Assuming you already called "import ray" and "ray.init()".

@ray.remote
def g(x):
    print(x)
```

You'll see that

```
g.remote(1)  # This prints '1'
g.remote(ray.put(1))  # This also prints '1'
g.remote([ray.put(1)])  # This prints '[ObjectID(feffffffe3f2116088b37cb305fbb2537b9783ee)]'
```

In the third line, because the argument is a list, the `ObjectID` inside the list is not replaced by its corresponding value.

In your example, you have

```
@ray.remote
def f(*xs):
    print(xs)
```

The difference between your **Version 1** and your **Version 2** is that in **Version 1**, you are passing in multiple `ObjectID` arguments. In **Version 2**, you are passing in a single argument which is a list containing multiple `ObjectID`s.

```
xs = [ray.put(1), ray.put(2)]
f.remote(*xs)  # This prints '(1, 2)'
f.remote(xs)  # This prints '([ObjectID(fcffffffe3f2116088b37cb305fbb2537b9783ee), ObjectID(fbffffffe3f2116088b37cb305fbb2537b9783ee)],)'
```

To do what you want, you may need to do something like this (essentially combining the two lists into one). It's not the prettiest, but it should work.

```
@ray.remote
def h(num_xs, *xs_and_ys):
    xs = xs_and_ys[:num_xs]
    ys = xs_and_ys[num_xs:]
    print(xs, ys)

x_ids = [ray.put(1), ray.put(2)]
y_ids = [ray.put(3), ray.put(4), ray.put(5)]

h.remote(len(x_ids), *(x_ids + y_ids))  # This prints '(1, 2) (3, 4, 5)'
```